# Can't launch Android App in my device

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I'm trying to run App that has a search in its action bar and also it shares in twitter. When I run my App, I got this message in console

```
 Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
 \Healthy_Tips2\bin\Healthy_Tips2.apk installed on device
 Done!
```

But I can't find my App with Apps menu in the device and the App is not launching..

The following is the code of my start activity manifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="com.emy.healthytips.MainActivity"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
          android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        <!-- enable the base activity to send searches to itself -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: and do you have all sizes of icons? i mean hdpi icon and mdpi icon?

Comment: in some cases, the launcher can't show large icons, so you need to define the smaller size of the icon

Comment: Uninstall and then install it.

Comment: I reinstalled it many times. I found it in the list of whole Apps. but can't see it in menu apps nor apps in background

Comment: please try this command using shell/cmd window  `adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName` where `com.package.name` is package path, and `com.package.name.ActivityName` is default `activity` path

Comment: if the app starts, then it does exists, if not, then there is a problem in installing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from uninstalling the previous app through adb like the others have already mentioned.

In your manifest, you should increment your versionCode="1" by 1 more and break down your intent filter into two. This will still work. An activity can have more than one intent-filter.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="com.emy.healthytips.MainActivity"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This solution make app launch and I found it in background apps but I can't find it in Apps Menu

Comment: A reference to your application launcher icon is either missing or incorrect. Please cut and paste your surrounding application tag and also take a look in your res/drawable/ folder to see what your launcher icon is called, or to see if it's even in there.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project -> clean -> run your project.

this will rebuild your project.

Then run your project again. Usually works. Or else are you sure you are not trying to run a library Project??

Comment: When I do clean, the eclipse deletes R.java :(

Comment: that means your xml has some error. please check your xml once.

Comment: like have not defined height or width attribute for some view.

Answer (score 2):

Use adb to uninstall your application:

```
adb uninstall package_name
```

See link:
http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-uninstall/how-to-use-adb-uninstall.html

**Edit:** Go to sdk/platformtools under command line tool. And write this line:

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make any change to your app. add a comment or so, or uninstall your app then deploy again.

Comment: I reinstalled it many times. I found it in the list of whole Apps. but can't see it in menu apps nor apps in background

Comment: how to use it? could you guide me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I try running my app without making changes when the app is already open.

Try closing/restarting your emulator/phone and reopening it.

Also try making a change to the app, then deleting it and save it (type "A" anywhere in the code then remove it).

Then try cleaning your project:  project > clean

If that doesn't work, try uninstalling the app after trying above methods and try again.  This should work.

Comment: I'm trying on real device not emulator

Comment: You can try restarting the phone, it might be stuck in your phones cache.

Comment: I made a huge change and reinstall. Still the same :(

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts with me, I tried to do changes and it helped to show the app in background apps

Answer (score 0):

I personally always have the same problem, when I'm trying to install an apk via phone, although it's already installed via PC. For me it works to simply deinstall the final app and try once more to install the apk.